# ng-show and ng-model can't work together on the same $scope variable

Tags: angularjs

I am trying to have a span element show some $scope variable only if it is not null or empty.

I know i can accomplish this with only ng-model, but i don't understand they this won't work:

```
<span ng-show="x !== null" ng-model="x"></span>
```

or something similar to this.

Comment: <span ng-show="x !== null" ></span> should work. no need to use ng-model

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ng-model` is used mostly for `input`, `textarea`, and `select` elements. It's not used on `span`, `div`, or `p` elements, etc.

From [Angular documentation on ngModel](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngModel)

> The ngModel directive binds an input,select, textarea (or custom form control) to a property on the scope using NgModelController, which is created and exposed by this directive.

Comment: Generally speaking, yes, it can't work. `ngModel` is for establishing two-way data binding between user input and JavaScript object. In your `span`, where's the user input? What are you trying to establish two-way data binding with?

Answer (score 2):

`ng-model` is for two-way binding (as @MK Safi said above), which means its for elements that both display values and allow users to change those values.  Probably not a `<span/>`...

If you're just looking to show the value of the model in the span, use `ng-bind` or expression syntax - `{{ x }}`

This way, ng-show should work properly to add the relevant CSS styles as x changes.

E.g.:

```
<span ng-bind="x" ng-show="x !== null"></span>
```

or

```
<span ng-show="x !== null">{{ x }}</span>
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, as MK Safi says `ng-model` is only used to bind inupts to `$scope` variables. This should work though:

```
<span ng-show="x !== null">{{ x }}</span>
```

Just use the templating engine to display the value in `$scope.x`